# Which space this space drawn in this picture is homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, intuition, visualization

Based in this question [Why this space is homeomorphic to the plane?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/272605/why-this-space-is-homeomorphic-to-the-plane) I would like to know which space this space is homeomorphic, any help or an intuitive idea are welcome.

[image]

[Context of Image: related to the problem from [this pdf document](http://www.math.psu.edu/ballif/assignments/Math%20527%20Topology-Geometry/MATH527_HW8.pdf).]

Thanks

Comment: The picture by itself does not provide enough information.

Comment: Where did you get this picture from?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This picture is in $\mathbb R^2$ with the identifications represented by the arrows.

Comment: @JacobSchlather in this link https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEIQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.psu.edu%2Fballif%2Fassignments%2FMath%2520527%2520Topology-Geometry%2FMATH527_HW8.pdf&ei=QqXsUNfqHoeC8ATBw4HwCA&usg=AFQjCNFRyKPcPhinGQF6AyWWd3Stg5yZrA&bvm=bv.1357316858,d.eWU

Comment: It's not. That space is homeomorphic to the Klein bottle. The lines and arrows are to show the identifications you make *on* $\mathbb R^2$ to *get* the Klein bottle.

Comment: Based on the context I believe Benjamin Lin's interpretation in your previous question was correct.

Comment: There’s more than one way to interpret the identifications. However, now that I’ve seen the PDF, I take it that each unit segment is to be identified with each other unit segment bearing the same kind of arrow.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you know where can I find another kinds of interpretations of identifications? I know just one type of interpretation in this case, identify the arrows in the same direction. Thank you for your comments :)

Comment: All of the interpretations that I had in mind involve identifying arrows in the same direction. The questions were whether the identification was by segment or by whole line, and whether the interiors of different squares were being identified as well as the edges.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott So in order to have the Klein bottle, the interiors of different squares have to be identified?

Comment: Yes; to get a Klien bottle, you have to collapse it down to one square and then identify the edges of that.